# Retrospectively adding TDD to Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, testing

Recently I have been working on a project recently ported a to laravel.

I would like to start testing new features that are being added, but I am worried about altering the database when running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

From [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing):

> #### Resetting The Database After Each Test
>
> It is often useful to reset your database after each test so that data from a previous test does not interfere with subsequent tests.
>
> ...
>
> **Using Transactions**
>
> Another option is to wrap every test case in a database transaction. Again, Laravel provides a convenient DatabaseTransactions trait that will automatically handle this

You may use `DatabaseTransactions` trait.

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;
```

I believe you already know it, but to avoid missunderstandings remember you shouldn't run your tests on a production environment, make a local copy.